# Does wpa_supplicant background scanning reduce wlan throughput?

Tags: android-wifi, wifi

In wpa_supplicant It is possible to enable periodic background scans.

Does frequent scan reduce wlan throughput ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
When scanning, working channels will be switched to other channels to send probe request. During this process, the normal data flow will stop transmission.

Answer (score 0):

PeopleMoutainPeopleSea is right.

Background scanning means that the WLAN client device (phone) will stop its current transmission for a short period of time in order to send out *probe request* frames and listen to *probe response* frames and *beacon* frames from access points.
This is usually done on all available channels. The device therefore needs to leave its current (working) channel and switch to another channel.

A single background scan only needs a few hundred milliseconds. This might be noticeable in applications such as VoIP calls, but not in web surfing, downloading etc.
However, the more frequently the background scans are performed, the less time can be used for data transmissions, which will lead to a lower average data throughput.